# How do i export as global variable

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumberjs, karate

I have a karate feature file

```
Scenario: Feature

Given url 'https://testlocal/v1/test/authorize'
And request 'type=code&uri=http://www.testlocal/app'
And header Accept = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
When method POST
Then status 302
* def code = responseHeaders['Location'][0].substring(59,95)
* print code
```

when i run the above feature file i can see the code being printed seperately, however I would like to use that code in the following of the same feature file

```
Scenario: Login

Given url 'https://testlocal/v1/test/authorize/login'
And request 'username=test1@gmail.com&password=123!&requestId=**"I am not sure how to call the above code here"**
And header Accept = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
When method POST
Then status 302
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a `Background:` section, refer to this as a good example of re-use: [`headers.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/headers.feature).

If you really need re-use across multiple feature files, refer to the documentation on how to [re-use feature files via the `call` keyword](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files).

I'd like to suggest an improvement to your test, you can do the following instead of manually forming the request, using the [`form field`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#form-field) syntax:

EDIT: full solution

```
Background:
Given url 'https://testlocal/v1/test/authorize'
And form field type = 'code'
And form field uri = 'http://www.testlocal/app'
When method post
Then status 302
And def code = responseHeaders['Location'][0].substring(59,95)

Scenario: login
Given path 'login'
And form field username = 'test1@gmail.com'
And form field password = '123!'
And form field requestId = code
When method post
Then status 302
```

Comment: Not wokring, @Peter Thomas

`java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: abc
 at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalInNashorn(Script.java:423)
 at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.evalList(StepDefs.java:137)
 at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.formField(StepDefs.java:225)
 at ✽.And form field requestId = abc(examples/users/users.feature:16)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "code" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1`

Comment: @wilfredcool007 try harder please. the code I provided is a best guess, and I can't say what the problem is from here. all the best.

Comment: for the time being just have all steps in one `Scenario` at least is that working for you ?

Comment: and using `Background:` instead of `Scenario:` for the first is not working ?

Comment: Ah, yes
The background just works fine ( I've been making a mistake all along ) Thanks very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158824/discussion-between-wilfredcool007-and-peter-thomas).